# DataStudio holds connections to DB2 database

Tags: database, db2-luw, ibm-data-studio

I run my queries on DB2 Datastudio. I start with "connect"ing to the database... and over a period of time.. say, I run 100+ queries on the same connection over multiple days.

On the database side, we see 100+ connections coming from me. I don't understand how 1 connection on my side can become 100+ connections on the database side? I use DataStudio v4.1.0.1. Please help..

Comment: Each SQL Editor window opens its own connection to the database and holds it until the window is closed.

Comment: I have a few sql editor windows open.. like 5 or 6. nothing more than that..

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL editor, head to configuration and pick "Use the existing connection". That should help fix it.